# How to ignore CMake Compiler Definitions in sub projects

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I have a main project that has several 3rd party libraries. I just added a new 3rd party project. The problem I'm facing is the new project breaks when the main project compiler definitions are passed to it.

How can I avoid passing these definitions to the 3rd party project?
Also, if the 3rd party project is compiled stand-alone, it only requires two include directories. But when compiled with the main project there are many extra directories passed to it.

I've tried looking for a set_definition() but I'm not seeing anything helpful.
Any links to examples or write ups will be nice. It might also be that I'm not looking for the right solution.
thanks

Comment: target_compile_definitions

Answer (score 1):

Using global 'add_definition' is old-approach. In present may be much better define compiler flags, defines etc. per [target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets), folder, source files etc. (in your case COMPILE_DEFINITIONS?)

Just google for 'modern CMake' and you will find slides and videos from conferences how to use modern CMake.